# map object keys from API using ES6 lodash

Tags: vue.js, dictionary, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm using Vue 3 for sending POST data to my API. The objects look like

```
const externalResults: ref(null)

const resource = ref({
  id: null,
  name: null,
  state: {}
})
```

Before sending the data to the API I'm parsing the `resource` object to avoid sending a nested object related to `state` property. So the payload sent looks like

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Lorem ipsum',
  state_id: 14
}
```

The API returns a 422 in case of missing/wrong data

```
{
  "message":"Some fields are wrong.",
  "details":{
    "state_id":[
       "The state_id field is mandatory."
    ]
  }
}
```

So here comes the question: how can I rename object keys in order to remove **always** the string `_id` from keys?

Since I'm using vuelidate I have to "map" the returned error details to model property names. Now I'm doing this to get details once the request is done

```
externalResults.value = e.response.data.details
```

but probably I will need something like

```
externalResults.value = e.response.data.details.map(item => { // Something here... })
```

I'd like to have a 1 line solution, no matter if it uses ES6 or lodash.
Please note that `state_id` is just a sample, there will be many properties ended with `_id` which I need to remove.

The expected result is

```
externalResults: {
  "state":[
       "The state_id field is mandatory."
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how long you allow your one-liners to be, but this is what I come up with in ECMAScript, using `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()` to disassemble and reassemble the object:

```js
const data = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Lorem ipsum',
  state_id: 14
};

const fn = (x) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(x).map(([k, v]) => [k.endsWith('_id') ? k.slice(0, -3) : k, v]));

console.log(fn(data));
```

You can shorten it a little more by using `replace()` with a regex:

```js
const data = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Lorem ipsum',
  state_id: 14
};

const fn = (x) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(x).map(([k, v]) => [k.replace(/_id$/, ''), v]));

console.log(fn(data));
```

---

If you use lodash, you can go shorter still by using the [`mapKeys()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mapKeys) function:

```js
const data = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Lorem ipsum',
  state_id: 14
};

const fn = (x) => _.mapKeys(x, (v, k) => k.replace(/_id$/, ''));

console.log(fn(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: All solutions work perfectly! Wondering if there is any kind of performance difference between them